# How can I complete my number guessing game?

Tags: java

My program should execute these steps:

1. Generate random no from 0 to 100.
2. Display random no and ask user enter `(h/l/c)`? (user have to enter one of them).
3. If it is correct ask user if they like to play again `(y/n)`? (user must answer `(y/n)`)

I was able to execute Question no.1. Question no.2, random no display but I am unable to type character `(h/l/c)`. Also, I am not able to ask player if they want to play again or not?

Here is what I have done:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class NumberGuessingGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        int number;
        int guess = 0;
        int min = 0;
        int max = 100;
        int answer= (min+max);

        number = (int) (Math.random() *100 +1);
        System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 100.");

        //Ask user to type higher 'h', lower 'l' and correct 'c'.
        System.out.println("Is it " + number + " ?" + " (h/l/c): " );

        //
        guess = 50;

        while (guess <= 7)
        {
            System.out.println( "It is: " + guess + "?" + "(h/l/c) : " );

            //Type 'h' if guess is high, 'l' for low and 'c' for correct. 
            if(answer == 'h')
            {
                max = guess -1;
                min = 0;
                guess = ((max = min)/2) + min;
                guess++;

            } else if (answer == 'l')
            {
                max = 100;
                min = guess + 1;
                guess = ((max+min)/2);
                guess++;
            } else if (answer == 'c');
        }
        System.out.println("Great! Do you want to play again? (y/n): ");

        if(answer == 'y')
        {
            System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 100.");
            //else prompt another question with if else
        } else{
             System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the documentation in the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help).  In particular, you should read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what sorts of questions are [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here at SO.

Comment: @siru, I would like to help you, but take azurefrog's advice. Ask a discrete question. What specifically is the problem? If you ask us to do your homework, you'll get downvoted till your question is closed.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to java programming and I only have basic knowledge. I am just practing to get better for myself in coding for future coding challege program. I watched many video tutorials where I didn't find what I was looking for that's why I am seeking help here.

Answer (score 0):

Your program does not accept any user input about if the guess is too low or too high.

You declared "answer" with an equation so it should accept a number.
answer would require a char or String value.

```
answer = keyboard.nextChar(); //read a char
answer = keyboard.nextLine(); //read a String
```